# Find images that have a certain HTML class name

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have some markup that contains certain HTML image tags with the class featured. What I need is to find all those images, add an anchor tag around the image, set the href attribute of the anchor to the images src value (the image path), and lastly replace the images src value with a new value (I call a method that will return this value).

```
<p>Some text here <img src="/my/path/image.png" alt="image description" class="featured" />. Some more text and another image that should not be modified <img src="/my/path/image2.png" alt="image description" /></p>
```

Should become.

```
<p>Some text here <a href="/my/path/image.png"><img src="/new/path/from/method.png" alt="image description" class="featured" /></a>. Some more text and another image that should not be modified <img src="/my/path/image2.png" alt="image description" /></p>
```

Comment: This can be done with jQuery on the client. Do you just need a one-off server-side find and replace style script or would you be able to implement this on your clients with jQuery?

Comment: Need to do this on the server so it works for those that don't have JavaScript or don't have JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use RegEx to parse HTML. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) classic SO answer for the reasons.

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) instead - you can use XPath to query your HTML.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into HTML Agility Pack

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this code.

```
using System;
```

using System.Reflection;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using log4net;

namespace Company.Web.Util
{
    public static class HtmlParser
    {
        private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        private static HtmlDocument _htmlDocument;

```
    public static string Parse(string input)
    {
        _htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();

        _htmlDocument.LoadHtml(input);
        ParseNode(_htmlDocument.DocumentNode);

        return _htmlDocument.DocumentNode.WriteTo().Trim();
    }

    private static void ParseChildren(HtmlNode parentNode)
    {
        for (int i = parentNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            ParseNode(parentNode.ChildNodes[i]);
        }
    }

    private static void ParseNode(HtmlNode node)
    {
        if (node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (node.Name == "img" && node.HasAttributes)
            {
                for (int i = node.Attributes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    HtmlAttribute currentAttribute = node.Attributes[i];
                    if ("class" == currentAttribute.Name && currentAttribute.Value.ToLower().Contains("featured"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string originaleImagePath = node.Attributes["src"].Value;

                            string imageThumbnailPath = GetImageThumbnail(originaleImagePath);

                            var anchorNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<a>");
                            var imageNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<img>");

                            imageNode.SetAttributeValue("alt", node.Attributes["alt"].Value);
                            imageNode.SetAttributeValue("src", imageThumbnailPath);

                            anchorNode.SetAttributeValue("href", originaleImagePath);

                            anchorNode.AppendChild(imageNode);
                            node.ParentNode.InsertBefore(anchorNode, node);

                            node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            if (_log.IsDebugEnabled)
                            {
                                _log.WarnFormat("Some message: {0}", exception);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (node.HasChildNodes)
        {
            ParseChildren(node);
        }
    }
}
```

}